# Combining objects in one list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts that looks like this:

```
{
   "Player_Name":"Byeong-Hun An",
   "Tournament":[
      {
         "Name":"Arnold Palmer Invitational presented by Mastercard",
         "Points":"32.80",
         "Salary":"10300.00"
      }
   ]
},
{
   "Player_Name":"Byeong-Hun An",
   "Tournament":[
      {
         "Name":"Different",
         "Points":"18.80",
         "Salary":"10400.00"
      }
   ]
}
```

and I want this:

```
[
   {
      "Player_Name":"Byeong-Hun An",
      "Tournament":[
         {
            "Name":"Arnold Palmer Invitational presented by Mastercard",
            "Points":"32.80",
            "Salary":"10300.00"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Different",
            "Points":"18.80",
            "Salary":"10400.00"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I've tried collections, but it doesn't do exactly what I'm wanting. I essentially want to take every single player and combine all the tournament objects into one so each player has one object instead of each event having its own object.

Here's my code

```
import json
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from collections import Counter
    
    # using json open the player objects file and set it equal to data
    with open('PGA_Player_Objects.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
    
    points = []
    players = []
    
    for a in data:
       for b in a['Tournament']:
           points.append(int(float(b['Points'])))
    
    for x in data:
        players.append(x['Player_Name'])
    
    def Average(lst):
        unrounded = sum(lst) / len(lst)
        return round(unrounded,2)
    
    result = Counter()
    for d in data:
        for b in d['Tournament']:
            result[d['Player_Name']] += int(float(b['Points']))
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your list is in `l`:

```
l = [{'Player_Name': 'Byeong-Hun An', 'Tournament': [{'Name': 'Arnold Palmer Invitational presented by Mastercard', 'Points': '32.80', 'Salary': '10300.00'}]},
     {'Player_Name': 'Byeong-Hun An', 'Tournament': [{'Name': 'Different', 'Points': '18.80', 'Salary': '10400.00'}]},]
```

Try this:

```
from itertools import groupby

result = [] 
for k,g in groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x:x['Player_Name']), lambda x:x['Player_Name']): 
    result.append({'Player_Name':k, 'Tournament':[i['Tournament'][0] for i in g]})
```

Then the result will be:

```
[{'Player_Name': 'Byeong-Hun An',
  'Tournament': [
      {'Name': 'Arnold Palmer Invitational presented by Mastercard',
       'Points': '32.80',
       'Salary': '10300.00'},
      {'Name': 'Different',
       'Points': '18.80', 
       'Salary': '10400.00'}]}]
```

Comment: Awesome that's exactly what I needed. I'll checkout out itertools!

Comment: @AustinJohnson Your willcome, please also consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: They are all adjacent

Comment: @AustinJohnson I have edited my answer for a time when they are not adjust.

Answer (score 1):

This works as well, and it's a more general solution that works for arbitrary key names:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for dic in lst:
    for k, v in dic.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            d[k].extend(v)
        else:
            d[k] = v

answer = [dict(d)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on a solution.

- Create a new list of dictionaries
- Iterate through the original list of dictionaries.

  - Store one copy of the beginning data for each player that is the same into the new list of dictionaries
  - Append additional Tournament data for each player into that one dictionary into a unified Tournament list.

Untested code below as an example, but should work with some tweaks.

```
listofDicts =   [{'Player_Name': 'Byeong-Hun An', 'Tournament': [{'Name': 'Arnold Palmer Invitational presented by Mastercard', 'Points': '32.80', 'Salary': '10300.00'}]},{'Player_Name': 'Byeong-Hun An', 'Tournament': [{'Name': 'Different', 'Points': '18.80', 'Salary': '10400.00'}]}]

newListOfDicts = []
playerName = " "
playerNo = -1
for dicts in listofDicts:
    if playerName == dicts['Player_Name']:
        newListOfDicts[playerNo]['Tournament'].append(dicts['Tournament'][0])
    else:
        newListOfDicts.append(dicts)
        playerName = dicts['Player_Name']
        playerNo += 1
```